# How to prevent `atime` in Linux from overwriting `Date created` in Windows on NTFS?

Tags: timestamps, ntfs, ntfs-3g, atime, noatime

From Linux, if I alter files on an NTFS external HD so that I get some specific values for `mtime`, `atime` and `ctime` (readable with the `stat` command, and with `ctime = mtime` because one cannot change access permissions of files on NTFS from Linux - I think) and if I then connect the same external HD on a Windows 7 system, I see that `Date modified = mtime` (as expected) but I also get `Date created = atime`.

How comes `atime` takes the placeholder associated with the NTFS `CTime` timestamp, and is there a way to avoid this behavior, for example would using the `noatime` option on NTFS volumes be a proper solution? My goal is to be able to work from both Windows and Linux on this same external HD without mingling too much the timestamps.

**Edit**

After re-investigating the issue, it turns out that the problem is not present in the end. I must have been confused at the time I asked the question. I still leave the question as it has generated some comments and an answer.

Comment: But is it true that Linux really don't support creation time?

Comment: I think that you are talking about a serious inode change to make this happen.

Comment: It's often a good idea to read existing Q&As before asking a question.  https://superuser.com/a/703927/38062 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/407305/5132 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562/5132 https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24441/5132

Comment: @JdeBP: I had already read all those Q&As. My question is not 'how to make Linux support creation times', it is 'how to make it *not* use the creation time placeholder of NTFS to put atime values.

Comment: You quite clearly have not read all of those, otherwise your question would not have the first sentence and third paragraph that it currently has.

Comment: @JdeBP: I see your point now. Thanks. I have rephrased the question.

Answer (score 0):

This was too big to write as a comment, but I think it can help.

Well if you want to avoid this behavior, you can do something like this:

```
 $current_ctime=$(getfattr -n system.ntfs_crtime_be -e hex yourfile | grep system.ntfs_crtime_be | cut -d= -f2)
```

Then after the changes restore the current_ctime using:

```
setfattr -n system.ntfs_crtime_be -v $current_ctime yourfile
```

For **multiple files**, you can store for example all the ctimes using a for loop and restoring them in the same way for each file.

Not very beautiful but it works.